# ClassCastException SAXParserFactory cannot be cast to javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory

Tags: jboss, classcastexception, xerces

I am trying to deploy an ear on Wildfly that was deployed on Websphere which has some sax parser dependencies.  When I employ xml-apis-2.0.2.jar I get this error:

java.lang.ClassCastException: __redirected.__SAXParserFactory cannot be cast to javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory

On the other hand, when I employ xercesImpl-2.11.0.SP4.jar, I get this error:

NoClassDefFoundError: org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler

What should I do to remove this error?